# Disable one of the textarea on same page of summernote modal

Tags: javascript, html

I am using WYSIWYG summer note modal editor..Here I am using 2 editors on the same page. I want to disable one of the editors instead of both the editor. I tried the following code but it is disabling both the editor

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.summernote-modal').summernote({height: 130});
 $(".note-editable").attr("contenteditable","false");</script>
```

[image: need to disable response text area]

Comment: If you want to disable second editor, what about remove it from the page at all..

Comment: It's not possible. I need to keep it there only concern is to disabled it

Comment: So try this: `$('.yourIdOrClass').summernote('disable');`

Comment: Tried Many times..still not working

Comment: This part here needs to be more specific `$(".note-editable")` should be something more like `$("#note_area_1 .note-editable")` so, if you can, have a look at the source and see if you can find a way to distinguish between the two text-areas.

Comment: Thak you so much @admcfajn.

Comment: @EvilsEmpire Very welcome my friend :)